# Eclipse Swing designer

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

Is there a plugin for Eclipse that can help with designing the Swing GUI like in Netbeans?

The WindowBuilder is too simple and primitive. For example:

[image]

it only allows me to place a component in one of the 5 pre-defined regions

The GUI designer in Netbeans is much, much more powerful

Comment: I think there is not any option there in eclipse, why don't you use NetBeans and copy code from there.

Comment: but I want to do everything in Eclipse, I just love it

Answer (score 0):

There is a port of the Mantisse GUI Editor from NetBeans to Eclipse.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/swing-gui-designer

Answer (score 0):

There actually is several options to how control components are placed in the window. In the Design tab of your class under the Layouts dropdown there are several options. For example there is an Absolute option which allows x and y coordinate precision in placing and moving components.